# The page you are looking for is temporarily unavailable. Please try again later

Tags: wordpress, nginx

I'm using a WordPress plugin called PilotPress, and I have some problems with it.
The thing is: PilotPress doesn't accept 2 sessions to be opened and if I was logged in with a user and this same user logs in with another browser, in the old session it returns an error that says:
[image]

I understand that, because it's a membership plugin, it doesn't accept two sessions to be opened at the same time but my only problem is that, I want the user to see something else because when they see this error they think it's a bug.

They don't know what to do so my question is: is there a way to, for example, kill the other session completely? Let me explain myself:

1. I open Google Chrome, I log in into my website.
2. I open Safari and log in to the website with the same user.
3. The user gets back into Google Chrome and sees the error that I attached in the email.

Now, I want the session to refresh itself so that if the user gets back to Google Chrome, it doesn't show the error message but rather, it shows the login form again so the user can log in.
Is this possible?

Comment: So if anyone had that problem i want to tell you that i talked to the Ontraport/Pilotpress guys and they provided an updated that helped solved this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Debug your Wordpress

```
WP_DEBUG #WP_DEBUG
```

WP_DEBUG is a PHP constant (a permanent global variable) that can be used to trigger the “debug” mode throughout WordPress. It is assumed to be false by default and is usually set to true in the **wp-config.php** file on development copies of WordPress.

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG', false );
```